# Magento 1.9 Send data from observer to phtml without block

Tags: magento-1.9

We create observer and want observer data in `.phtml` file of my custom module. how we can get data without using block.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**Register your data in your observer**

```
Mage::register('name-of-registry-key', $your_data);
```

**Get your data using registry in your phtml file**

```
$your_data = Mage::registry('name-of-registry-key');
```

Comment: He asked for M1 change your code accordingly and you dont know M1 then let me know I will answer

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Thank you. I didn't notice the Magento version.